# JPA One-to-One Integrity Constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;

    //getters, setters...

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {

    public Child() {
    }

    public Child(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private Parent parent;

    //getters, setters...
}
```

The problem is the following. The process I use to update these entities is usually the following. First I do

```
Parent p = new Parent();
p.setId("parentId1");
em.persist(p);
```

So in this case the `Child` entitiy is `null`

Later on I may want to add a child entity so I do something like the following:

```
Parent parent = em.findById(parent.getId());
Child child = new Child(parent);
em.persist(child);
```

Now I assume that since Parent has the @MapsId annotation it should normally generate the id for Child by copying the Parent Id and the entity should be persisted. However, I am getting the following Constraint violation exception.

```
SqlExceptionHelper: Duplicate entry 'parentId1' for key 'PRIMARY'

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement;
```

Comment: Well, that means your parent already has a child. Also, the child's ID shouldn't be annotated with GeneratedValue.